# An experiment consists in throwing a die twice

Tags: probability, statistics

An experiment consists in throwing a die twice. Knowing that none of the launches provides the same result, calculate the probability that exactly one of the two launches gives as a result $1$.

So if I say $A=${the results of the two launches are different} and $B=${exactly one of the two launches gives as a result $1$} I have to calculate $P(B|A)$ which is equal to $P(B∩A)/P(A)$.

My problem is, how can I calculate the intersection between B and A? Regarding $P(A)$ I suppose it is equal to $30/36$ because $30$ are the favorable cases ($6*5$) and $36$ are the possible cases ($6*6$).

Answer (score 1):

B is a subset of A because B states that it is impossible to have 2 ones thrown. so $P(A \cap B) = P(B)$. The probability that exactly one 1 is thrown is P(1 on first throw | !1 on second throw) + P(1 on second throw | !1 on first throw) or $1/6*(5/6) + 1/6*(5/6) = 10/36$

Comment: if A is a subset of B then the intersection should be P(A)

Comment: ... corrected. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you did on the second part of the answer. Why did you sum those two probabilities?

Comment: and what does the $!$ mean?

Comment: They can be summed because they are mutually exclusive. It's equivalent to 2 choose 1 * 1/6 * 5/6.

Comment: the ! means "not"

Comment: but doing $1/6*5/6+1/6*5/6$ and dividing this by $30/36$ I get a probability of $2.4$ which is impossibile because the probability should always be equal or less than $1$

Comment: (10/36) / (30/36) = 1/3

Comment: actually it's $10/30$

Comment: ok I still don't understand what mutally exclusive mean, can you explain me?

Comment: yep. if there is no way for two things to happen at the same time, they are mutually exclusive. so, the probability of either rolling a 1 or a 2 is 1/6 + 1/6 or 2/6.

Comment: or when the intersection of two events is empty